# Using asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client how to check if cell is empty without triggering an error

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

Using asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client headers have to be set before updating or inserting rows. When users select a sheet I want to check if the headers are what I want them to be or if they are missing. I was trying to get the contents of cell(1,1) and if it was not equal to what I want then create all headers. The problem is, if cell(1,1) is empty I get a

"PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getContent() on a non-object"

How do I check for empty without getting an error while making the call?

Here is my code:

```
$cellFeed = $worksheet->getCellFeed();
$cell1 = $cellFeed->getCell(1,1)->getContent();
if ($cell1 !== 'datein'){
  $cellFeed->editCell(1,1, 'datein');
  $cellFeed->editCell(1,2, 'timein');
  $cellFeed->editCell(1,3, 'dateout');
  $cellFeed->editCell(1,4, 'timeout');
  $cellFeed->editCell(1,5, 'note');
}
```

The solution thanks to @eddyparkinson

```
$cell1 = $cellFeed->getCell(1,1)

if (!is_object($cell1)  || $cell1->getContent() !== 'datein'){
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you check if  $cellFeed->getCell(1,1) returns an object.

### CellFeed return values

The CellFeed only returns cells that have a value. It returns a sparse list of cells. There is no object to get the content of.